# Is the torque adequate?

Tags: motors, torque

I have a 10 pound flywheel attached to a 200w motor that has a torque rating of 280Nm that can achieve a 12000 rpm. The gear ratio to the inner axial of the flywheel is roughly 1:1 which is 48mm in diameter for the drive gear and 48mm in diameter for the gear around the flywheel axle.

Also using standard bearings.

There is no load on the flywheel and the only thing the motor has to overcome is the interia and drag of the flywheel.

My question is - how can I tell if the torque is adequate enough and could the flywheel achieve a 12000 rpm itself from the motor?

Comment: I hope you have calculated the amount of energy a 10 pound flywheel will have at 12000 rpm.  That's a lot of damage if it comes apart of comes off the shaft.  And it is very difficult to balance rotating machinery at such high speeds.

Comment: The flywheel wheel is being professionally balanced to remove any vibrations.

Answer (score 1):

1. You need enough torque to overcome rolling and static friction to actually maintain whatever speed you are currently at.
2. Any extra torque beyond that is dependent on how long you are willing to wait to accelerate up to speed.
3. Your motor has to be large enough that it doesn't stall and burn out before then.

Comment: God answer.  It might take along time to spool up to 12,000 rpm and it will be at a heavy current draw until it does.

Comment: although implicit in "need," it is worth mentioning that if 12000 is the 0-load max speed of the motor, it will not reach that under load.  the max rpm can be calculated from the torque requirements and the torque vs speed curve of the motor.